# Control Program UI Externally

Tags: python, c++, user-interface, hardware, resolve

I'll try to be as concise as possible:

Quite some time ago, I started using arduinos and other microcontrollers as custom MIDI devices for my PC.

But now, since I'm into filmmaking, I wanted to create a grading panel for use in Blackmagic's DaVinci Resolve. What i want exactly is to read signals from knobs and slider with a microcontroller and send the data to my PC so that Resolve can use it to apply different adjustments.

Unfortunately, since there are many different adjustments, there are no keyboard shortcuts for them, so I can't just emulate them with the microcontroller.

I have tried to use Cheat Engine to see if those adjustments values where stored somewhere in memory, but I can't seem to find them.

Resolve does have a Python and Lua API, but they're extremely limited and don't offer ANY control over color adjustements anyway.

I know that a few people that had my same idea used another software that mapped MIDI input to mouse movement, but I hate that solution, since the UI not only must be visible at all time, but you also can't change UI elements without needing to 're-calibrate' the mapping software.

To clarify: I'm not asking for code, I'm asking for 'directions'. How can I control a 3rd party software with custom made hardware? (I'm on Windows 10 btw)

Comment: See if that program exposes [Active Accessibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/microsoft-active-accessibility) hooks. MSAA allows applications to be controlled by assistive devices used by people with disabilities, which sounds kinda close to what you are trying to do. There are [tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/testing-tools) you can use to check what the program made availalbe.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thank you for the answer, you opened a world. I've been looking at MSAA and UIA and the tool recognizes text fields which I guess means that Resolve does expose those hooks. Now I need to figure out the individual IDs of those settings and write some code.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to do the exact same thing with DR. Unimpressed by the idea of glorified mouse macros and lack of color control in the official API. I had the idea to somehow "sniff" the memory values or inject myself into the Qt UI, but not sure where to even begin.